# implicit instantiation of function template

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following code which I conceived solely in order to practice function templates.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
T fun( const T &t ) { return t; }

struct A {
    int dataf;
    A( int a ) : dataf(a) { std::cout << "birth\n"; }
    friend A fun( const A & );
};

int main(){
    A a( 5 );
    fun( a );   
    return 0;
}
```

Though I get the following error:

```
code.cc:(.text+0x32): undefined reference to `fun(A const&)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I understand well class templates, but I am still confused about function templates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the friend declaration to:

```
template <class T> friend T fun( const T & );
```

or to:

```
friend A fun<A>( const A & );
```

Comment: +1 for the "or to." The second one matches the original intent.

Comment: I'd be thankful if you just added what is the difference between the two and information how they relate to the ideas of implicit and explicit specialisations. Thanks.

Comment: Also, I thought that given the template declaration, compiler can guess the specialisation from the context of a call and I do not have to provide any info that a function origins from a template whatsoever. Does the friendship declaration force special treatment or am I confusing things?

Comment: @yauser The difference between the two is that in the first the compiler will deduce the type `T` when the function is used. But the second is an explicit instantiation of the function template. The compiler can't deduce the types from the declaration alone, which is why I added `<A>` for the parameter type. Friend declarations are a special case in which you must do this.

Answer (score 0):

Normal functions are prefered over function templates during overload resoulution. The declaration of a free friend function inside `A` is an exact match for the call in `main`. The declaration is all that compiler needs to pick it up, so it compiles fine, but the linker can't find a definition because, well, you never defined it.